# What is the Maximum duration for Blessing?

Tags: warframe

The Warframe Trinity has a move called Blessing that gives all players invulnerability as well as full shields and HP. If I have a maxed out Continuity, Constitution, and Narrow Minded, how long will my Blessing last (assume Blessing is maxed too)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Blessing:

Default (max level blessing) = 10s

With Continuity (+30%) = 13s

With Constitution (+28%) = 12.8s

With Narrow Minded: (99%) = 19.9s

With all + [Aura Helmet](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Aura_Trinity_Helmet) (30% + 28% + 99% + 25%) = 28s

Source: [WF Wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity)

Answer (score 0):

Aura helmet is 25%. Max duration blessing is still 28s.